# " error: $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: now "10.3" but "10.6" during configure" when attempting to pip install different packages?

Tags: python, pygame, pip, homebrew

I've attempted to install different packages, such as `pygame` and `numpy` and I continually get this error:

```
error: $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: now "10.3" but "10.6" during configure
```

I've attempted to :

```
$ export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
```

before running the pip install but the error remains the same?  I'm trying to setup `pygame`, any idea what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Had to remove everything completely and reinstall , which seemed to fix the problem.